# glmnet / glmnetUtils: Repeated cross-validation

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to run repeated 10-fold CV (`alpha` and `lambda`) using `glmnet` / `glmnetUtils`. My proposed workflow is to:

a) fit a proposed model at 11 values of `alpha`,

b) run the process X (in this case, 10) times,

c) average the results, and

d) fit a final model with the best combination of `alpha` and `lambda` (`s = "lambda.1se"`).

To address a-c, I used the code below; however, the results from the 10 iterations are exactly the same.

```
library(glmnet)
library(glmnetUtils)
library(doParallel)

data(BinomialExample)


# Create alpha sequence; fix folds

alpha <- seq(.5, 1, .05)

set.seed(1)
folds <- sample(1:10, size = length(y), replace = TRUE)


# Determine optimal combination of alpha and lambda; extract lowest CV error and associated lambda at each alpha

extractGlmnetInfo <- function(object)
{
  # Find lambdas
  lambda1se <- object$lambda.1se

  # Determine where lambdas fall in path
  which1se <- which(object$lambda == lambda1se)

  # Create data frame with selected lambdas and corresponding error
  data.frame(lambda.1se = lambda1se, cv.1se = object$cvm[which1se])
}


#Run glmnet

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)

enet <- foreach(i = 1:10,
                .inorder = FALSE,
                .multicombine = TRUE,
                .packages = "glmnetUtils") %dopar%
  {
    cv <- cva.glmnet(x, y,
                     foldid = folds,
                     alpha = alpha,
                     family = "binomial",
                     parallel = TRUE)
    }

stopCluster(cl)


# Extract smallest CV error and lambda at each alpha for each iteration of 10-fold CV
# Calculate means (across iterations) of lowest CV error and associated lambdas for each alpha

cv.rep1 <- ldply(enet[[1]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep2 <- ldply(enet[[2]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep3 <- ldply(enet[[3]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep4 <- ldply(enet[[4]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep5 <- ldply(enet[[5]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep6 <- ldply(enet[[6]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep7 <- ldply(enet[[7]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep8 <- ldply(enet[[8]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep9 <- ldply(enet[[9]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)
cv.rep10 <- ldply(enet[[10]]$modlist, extractGlmnetInfo)

cv.rep <- bind_rows(cv.rep1, cv.rep2, cv.rep3, cv.rep4, cv.rep5, cv.rep6, cv.rep7, cv.rep8, cv.rep9, cv.rep10)

cv.rep <- data.frame(cbind(alpha, cv.rep))
```

**Questions**

1. My understanding is that the folds should be fixed when cross-validating over `alpha`. Therefore, should I `set.seed()` multiple times to generate different `folds` for each iteration and run each iteration separately, rather than looping over them? For example:

   ```
   # Set folds for first iteration

   set.seed(1)
   folds1 <- sample(1:10, size = length(y), replace = TRUE)


   # Run first iteration

   enet1 <- cva.glmnet(x, y,
                   foldid = folds1,
                   alpha = alpha,
                   family = "binomial")


   # Set folds for second iteration

   set.seed(2)
   folds2 <- sample(1:10, size = length(y), replace = TRUE)


   # Run second iteration

   enet2 <- cva.glmnet(x, y,
                   foldid = folds2,
                   alpha = alpha,
                   family = "binomial")
   ```
2. Or is there a way to fix the `folds` and loop over the iterations, thereby making use of parallel processing?
3. Re: the option presented in 1., how do I determine which configuration of `folds` I should use to fit the final model using the optimal combination of `alpha` and `lambda`? Is the decision arbitrary?

**NB.** I am not using `caret` for this specific task.